# PHP serve command error in Laravel project

Tags: server, php, laravel

I just installed Laravel with all the requirements (`php`, `composer`, `nodejs`) and created a new project called `blogg`. When I run `php artisan serve`
it returns an error saying that `autoload.php` does not exist in the directory.
See the error below:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/home/tibsis/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/blogg/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tibsis/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/blogg/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/tibsis/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/blogg/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/tibsis/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/blogg/artisan on line 18
```

I tried copying the `autoload.php` file from the `vendor` folder and pasting into my `blogg` project's folder and it still did not work.

How do I fix this? Do I have to reinstall everything from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload
composer install / composer update
```